# how did we breed after the fusion ? and why can't we bread with chimps?

Tags: genetics, evolution, human-genetics, chromosome, sexual-reproduction

after the chromosome fusion happened to one of our ancestors, how did he breed ? if he was allowed to breed because the chromosomal differences were still not very big back then, why can donkey and horse breed then ? ain't we supposed to be able to breed with chimps as well ?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of people today with balanced Robertsonian translocations, they breed mostly fine, though Down's is more common than in the rest of the population, because meiosis is more likely to be messed up. If due to drift, people with those translocations became more common, eventually they could breed with each other, and make offspring with 22 pairs of chromosomes.  In theory, this drift could take over the whole human population.

Answer (score 0):

Fusion of chromosome is not an absolute barrier. The two unfused chromosomes can pair up with the fused chromosome.

So long as all the genes are the same... offspring can be had.

However... a fused chromosome means that chromosome cross overs between the fused chromosome and its unfused chromosomes during meiosis will lead to unequal crossover of the chromosome, leading to massive lost or gain of genes... such germ cells if fertilized is usually lethal

Also if the fused chromosome is reassorted unequally with its unfused chromosomes during gamete formation.. will also lead to unbalanced genes for any fertilised embriyo... so again it is lethal.

So while there will be offspring... there will be few.

In effect... the fused chromosome creates a barrier.. not an absolute barrier... but one that makes free flow difficult.

So back to your question... the first individual with the fused chromosome could have reproduced by with a lower fitness with any member of the tribe. There will be children but it would be few. Those children with the fused chromosome can again reproduce with any member of the tribe but will have few children. However if two individuals with fused chromosome mate (sibling-sibling / parent-sibling) the pair will be fully fertile.

An interesting example
http://genetics.thetech.org/original_news/news124

Man with 44 chromosome instead of 46... Man has two chromosome composed of chr14-15 fusion. Produce of parents who are first cousin who both also have the Chr14-15 fusion.

Perhaps one day in the far future... this Man will be source of people with 44 chromosome.

Other example are families with balance translocation of chr21. They have a high incidence of down syndrome in the family.

As for Horse (2n=64) and Donkeys (2n=62).. not only is there chromosome fusion, but enough time has passed that changes in genes has occurred... ie specialization. As a result the reproductive cycles of jennies are affected.  Also Johns, are gelded as a matter of course. So no fertility to speak off. That being said, there have been instance of Jennies becoming pregnant and giving birth.. usually to a pure donkey (if sire is donkey) or pure horse (if the sire is horse)... an indication of some kind selective segregation of donkey and horse chromosomes... Perhaps donkey and horse centromeres do not play well together.

Comment: so you mean that we can't breed with chimps whilst donkeys can breed with horses because our speciation happened much earlier ? and not because of the number of chromosomes nor the differences of the genetic information ?